# Observable not refreshing the view - Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rxjs

When I call `login()` or `logout()` in auth.service.ts from login.ts component after showing facebook popup, the `isAuth` remain false in the home view but if I do `console.log(this.isAuth)` inside `subscribe()` it updates correctly in console.

When I call `login()` or `logout()` directly without using firebase facebook login, **It works fine**.

**Home**

HTML

```
 <h1> {{isAuth}} </h1>
```

TS

```
 isAuth = false;

 constructor(private _auth:AuthService) {
    _auth.authState.subscribe(state => this.isAuth = state)
   }
```

**AuthService**

```
authState = new Subject<boolean>();

login(access_token) {
    this.authState.next(true);
  }

 logout() {
    this.authState.next(false);
  }
```

Subject is imported from

> import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

**login.ts**

```
signInWithFacebook() {
    this.afAuth.auth
      .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
      .then((res: any) => {
        const access_token = res.credential.accessToken;
        this._auth.login(access_token);
        this._router.navigateByUrl('/home');      
      });
```

the facebook promise is solved and the `this._auth.login()` is called and the `isAuth` is changed but the view is not updated...

Comment: Try to listen to router.events.subscribe(event:Event =>console.log) to check if firebase login do somd redirection that affects your navigation to home. And maybe wrap your navigation in setTimeout call with some delay - just to check.

Comment: Hello, the routing works well. It goes from login to home, but in the home view the this.isAuth should change from false to true if user is logged. The this.isAuth only does change in console.

Comment: I think home component is recreated when you route to it(just put console.log to ngOnInit to make sure). So previous true value( from subject.next) will be lost. You better save it in some service and then use it home component.

Comment: actually the isAuth is in the header.ts not in home.ts though I just did _router.events.subscribe(event =>console.log(event)) and it outputs something about '/home' and '/login' but nothing about "header" component  which isn't in the app routing module

Comment: Try subscribe in ngOnInit, not in constructor

Comment: @Eliseo I already tried that but same result.. It throw this warning "Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?"... I'm using Angular 7.0

Comment: can you try and inject ChangeDetectorRef, and after assing the value to `isAuth`, do this `this.cdr.markForCheck();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try NgZone

ts

```
isAuth = false;

constructor(private _auth:AuthService, private ngZone: NgZone) {
ngZone.run(() => {
   _auth.authState.subscribe(state => this.isAuth = state)
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello, I just tried NgZone but still not working. I edited my post and added the login.ts. I'm doing Facebook login using Firebase.

Comment: When is you login.ts executed? Is it before or after the constructor that from the second code snippet?

Comment: The login.ts is called firstly. It resolves the facebook login promise and call the authService and change the route to home.

Comment: when you log this line `_auth.authState.subscribe(state => this.isAuth = state)`, does the `isAuth` is what you expected?

Comment: Yes, the this.isAuth change from false to true when logged but the view does not change. From other side, when I do the loggin flow but without calling firebase facebook login, all work as expected.

Comment: I am not sure about that.

Comment: I think, you should mark it for dirty check, so that angular detects the changes and evaluates the expression.

Comment: what if you replace `ngZone.run` with `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` ?